# How were these values of sin x found?

Tags: trigonometry

I'm working on Trigonometry problems that have to do with inverse functions.

So I have an example problem that goes like this:

$$\ 10\sin^2x = \sin x$$

and apparently the solution set is:

$\sin x = 0 $ if $ x = 0.0 , 3.1$

and $\sin x =  1/10$ if $ x = 0.1, 3.0$

I know how to do these problems in terms of radians, but I don't know what these integers are referring to on the unit circle, because when I assume that 1 = 360 degrees, the equations still don't make sense.

Can someone please help me with how these values were computed? I can't find any examples in my textbook.

Thank you!

Comment: Where did you see this?  This indeed looks rather strange...

Comment: It's directly from the web app that my professor uses to handle homework and exam reviews.

Comment: the 1/10 is there because I couldn't type 1 over 10 with the format, and I would like to add that all this is directly from the program. Those are the supposed correct answers, and I want to know how they were found.

Comment: Oh my goodness, I'm so sorry. I somehow neglected to include the 10 at the beginning of the equation. I have edited it to make it accurate to the actual problem.

Comment: The equation is equivalent to
 $$\sin x (10 \sin x -1) = 0. $$
Does that help you?

Comment: What grade level is your textbook?

Comment: Bottom line: your program is wrong. Sorry I can't help you any more. TBH I can already tell this is about to become a heated debate. I don't really care for heated debates.

Comment: @user254665 College first year trigonometry

Comment: @ChetSpalsky Are you allowed to use a calculator ?

Comment: @callculus yes, I am.

Comment: In general if $\sin(x)=b$ for some $-1\le b\le1$ then $x$ can be any even multiple of $\pi$ plus $\arcsin(b)$ or any odd multiple of $\pi$ minus $\arcsin(b)$. Here is a GeoGebra illustration of the arcsine function. https://www.geogebra.org/m/nJfeeyk7

Comment: Then take the equation from Eff and conclude that $\sin(x)=0$. and $10\sin(x)-1=0$. One solution of the first equation is $0$. This result you should know by heart. The solution of the second equation can be found by transformation. $10sin(x)=1\Rightarrow \sin(x)=\frac{1}{10}\Rightarrow x=sin^{-1}\left( \frac{1}{10}\right)$ now use the calculator.

Comment: @callculus Yes, I know how to get that far, but the two other answers (3.0, 3.1) are what I'm having trouble with. I have no idea how this is calculated.

Comment: Perhaps 3.1 is a (poor) approximation to $\pi$, 0.1 is an approximation to $\arcsin\frac{1}{10}$, and 3.0 is a (poor) approximation to $\pi - \arcsin\frac{1}{10}$.

Comment: @rogerl I believe this is indeed the case. Thanks everyone for the help!

Comment: There are clearly an infinite number of solutions, by the way.

Comment: See because $sinx=1/10$ is not at all a standard value, nobody simply knows such values (which are not standing like that of $sinx=1/2$ or$sinx=\sqrt{3}/2$ and hence such values are computed by the use of a calculator or a trigonometric table.

Comment: BTW, when you are asked to find the solutions, you can use simple trigonometric function definitions for general solutions. http://www.sparknotes.com/math/trigonometry/trigonometricequations/section1.rhtml

Comment: This makes perfect sense to me. Divide both sides by sin(x), then divide both sides by 10. Then you have sin(x)=1/10, which is what the given answer shows.

Answer (score 3):

Definition of radian comes from circular arc length:

\begin{align*} r\theta &= 2\pi r \times \frac{\alpha}{360^{\circ}} \\
  \frac{\theta}{\alpha} &= \frac{\pi}{180^{\circ}} \\[5pt]
  \pi \text{ rad} &= 180^{\circ} \\
  1 \text{ rad} &= \frac{180^{\circ}}{\pi} \\
  1^{\circ} &= \frac{\pi}{180} \text{ rad}
\end{align*}

> $$\sin \beta=y$$
>
> $$\implies \beta=180n^{\circ}+(-1)^{n}\sin^{-1} y
>                   =n\pi+(-1)^{n}\sin^{-1} y$$

Now, $$10\sin^2 x = \sin x \implies \sin x(10\sin x-1) = 0$$

$$\sin x=0 \quad \text{or} \quad \sin x=\frac{1}{10}$$

For $0\leq x < 2\pi$,

$$x=0 \, , \, \pi \, , \, \sin^{-1} 0.1 \, , \, \pi-\sin^{-1} 0.1$$

Comment: The least positive solution to sin x=0.1 is about  0.100167. Calculating the inverse sine, in general, requires some results from calculus.